# Composite property object that inhibits multiple signal emissions when all subobjects are changed

Tags: c++, signals, composite, c++17

I have a simple `property<T>` class with a `value_changed<T>` which you can `connect`/`disconnect` to and receive or inhibit events when `value_changed<T>::emit(T)` is called. Think Qt signal/slots on C++11 steroids.

My next challenge is to provide a property-like object that is composed of sub-properties. Think about for example, a position, or size, which both consist of multiple values. I would like to be able to treat the subobjects as `property`, and additionally get a composed signal emitted when multiple values are changed at once. E.g. doing

```
struct 
{
  property<int> x;
  property<int> y;
}
position2d pos{0,0};
// ...
pos = {1,1}; // this should fire x.value_changed, y.value_changed, and pos.value_changed (once!)
```

This last little word is the core of the problem. I'm struggling to code a *reusable* `composite_property` that can be customized with subobject names (position would get `x`,`y`, but size would get `width`/`height`).

Note a `property<struct { int x; int y; }>` doesn't suffice: changing `x` won't emit the composite `value_changed` signal.

The best I can come up with is something with a bunch of boilerplate code to connect/disconnect the subobjects when assigning to the superobject, which is tedious and goes against the DRY principle.

I'm open to wild template magic, although I understand the free naming of the variables (`x`/`y` and `width`/`height`) will make at least some boilerplate code necessary.

**EDIT** For completeness, this is the `property` template as I have it now:

```
template<typename T>
class property
{
public:
  using value_type = T;
  using reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>;
  using const_reference = std::add_lvalue_reference_t<std::add_const_t<T>>;
  using rvalue_reference = std::add_rvalue_reference_t<T>;

  property(const_reference value_ = {}) : value(value_) {}

  operator const_reference() const { return value; }

  property& operator=(const_reference& other)
  {
    const bool changed = value != other;
    value = other;
    if(changed)
      value_changed.emit(value);

    return *this;
  }

  bool operator==(const_reference other) const { return value == other; }
  bool operator!=(const_reference other) const { return value != other; }
  bool operator< (const_reference other) const { return value <  other; }
  bool operator<=(const_reference other) const { return value <= other; }
  bool operator> (const_reference other) const { return value >  other; }
  bool operator>=(const_reference other) const { return value >= other; }

  signal<value_type> value_changed;

  private:
    value_type value;
};
```

`signal` is a bit more involved, and is available [here](https://github.com/rubenvb/skui/blob/master/core/signal.h%2B%2B). Basically, `connect` like Qt, except that it returns a `connection_type` object like Boost.Signal, which can be used to `disconnect` that connection.

Note I'm open to a backdoor "modify property silently" function that bypasses the signal, but that only implements half of what I need.

Comment: Are you reinventing WPF static properties? :)

Comment: @Vladislav: I'm actually trying to bring some of Qt's macro and moc magic to standard, sane, compact, C++. So not so much reinventing as creating a new and improved implementation.

Comment: If you're willing to radically change the definition of `position2d`, then this can probably be achieved without repeating the names `x` and `y`, but it won't be nice to the class definition: it would involve, for example, moving all properties into a tuple (or tuple-like template), providing convenient IDs for the members, probably throwing some macros into the mix, a better access interface than `tuple`'s, and so on. No, I don't think that would be a good idea. Compile-time reflection would obviously give you what you want.

Comment: Since we don't have that, the next best thing I can think of is a solution that would only repeat the member names once: something like `composite_property<position2d, &position2d::x, &position2d::y> pos_prop;` is achievable in C++17, I think. If you're interested in such a solution, I can give it a try. It would be good if you included a skeleton version of `property<T>` on which an answer could be based.

Comment: @bogdan I included my `property<T>` and a link to `signal<T>`. The latter is a bit long to include in the question directly. You made me curious :).

Comment: @rubenvb Hoping the bounty doesn't bother you. I liked the question and I'm just willing to draw attention. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack Why would it bother me? The more the merrier!

Comment: I've just come across [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/5kyuos/serializing_structs_with_c17_structured_bindings/). While it was good fun to read, I wouldn't use such a solution in a real library - too easy to break in unexpected ways in my opinion. There's only so far I'm willing to go with hacking the language to compensate for deficiencies, and this crosses the line :-). Whether you're willing to use something like that to avoid naming the members in simple cases similar to `position2d` is ultimately your decision, of course. cc @skypjack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question is tagged [c++1z](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z), here's a simple solution that's using some shiny new C++17 features (along the lines discussed in the comments above):

```
template<class T, auto... PMs> struct composite_property : property<T>
{
   using const_reference = typename property<T>::const_reference;

   composite_property(const_reference v = {}) : property<T>(v)
   {
      (... , (this->value.*PMs).value_changed.connect([this](auto&&)
         {
            if(listen_to_members) this->value_changed.emit(this->value);
         }));
   }

   composite_property& operator=(const_reference& other)
   {
      listen_to_members = false;
      property<T>::operator=(other);
      listen_to_members = true; // not exception-safe, should use RAII to reset
      return *this;
   }

private:
   bool listen_to_members = true;
};
```

Out of sheer laziness, I've made a change to your `property<T>`: I've made `value` public. Of course, there are several ways to avoid that, but they're unrelated to the problem at hand, so I opted to keep things simple.

We can test the solution using this toy example:

```
struct position2d
{
   property<int> x;
   property<int> y;

   position2d& operator=(const position2d& other)
   {
      x = other.x.value;
      y = other.y.value;
      return *this;
   }
};

bool operator!=(const position2d& lhs, const position2d& rhs) { return lhs.x.value != rhs.x.value || lhs.y.value != rhs.y.value; }

int main() 
{
   composite_property<position2d, &position2d::x, &position2d::y> pos = position2d{0, 0};

   pos.value.x.value_changed.connect([](int x) { std::cout << " x value changed to " << x << '\n'; });
   pos.value.y.value_changed.connect([](int y) { std::cout << " y value changed to " << y << '\n'; });
   pos.value_changed.connect([](auto&& p) { std::cout << " pos value changed to {" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "}\n"; });

   std::cout << "changing x\n";
   pos.value.x = 7;
   std::cout << "changing y\n";
   pos.value.y = 3;
   std::cout << "changing pos\n";
   pos = {3, 7};
}
```

Here's a [live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/E6xxbmniCqGjmfqp) with all the necessary definitions included (my code is at the bottom).

While having to list the members explicitly as arguments to the `composite_property` template can be annoying, it also provides quite a bit of flexibility. We can have, for example, a class with three member properties and define different composite properties over different pairs of member properties. The containing class is not affected by any of this and can also work independently of any composite properties, with the members used as standalone properties.

Note that there's a reason for the user-provided copy assignment operator of `position2d`: if we left it defaulted, it would copy the member properties themselves, which doesn't emit signals, but rather duplicates the source properties.

The code works on Clang trunk in C++1z mode. It also causes an ICE on GCC trunk; we should try to reduce the example to get something that can be submitted in a bug report.

The crucial C++17 feature at work here is `auto` non-type template parameters. In previous language versions, there are some much uglier alternatives, for example, wrapping the pointers to members in something like `ptr_to_mem<decltype(&position2d::x), &position2d::x>`, possibly using a macro to avoid the repetition.

There's also a fold expression over `,` in the implementation of the constructor of `composite_property`, but that can also be done (in a slightly more verbose way) by initializing a dummy array.

Comment: I don't like that much this: `composite_property<position2d, &position2d::x, &position2d::y> pos`. Explicitly specify the parameters can quickly become annoying. Anyway, I see why you did it. That said: chapeau. :-)

Comment: @skypjack I don't like it that much either, but, as I said in the comments to the question, I don't think we can do much better than this without compile-time reflection in the language (if we want a sane definition for `position2d`).

Comment: @skypjack I've just added a link to a live example if you want to play with it.

Comment: I would probably go with indexed properties, but OP request is to access them by name and this sets several limitations. Good answer anyway. +1

Comment: Thank you so much!! 11PM here, but I'll give it a chance tomorrow. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack OP's special request is what got me interested; otherwise, a tuple-like composite property is straightforward to implement, but it doesn't provide the same flexibility. We could have a class with three member properties, defined naturally as above, and then define different composite properties over any pair of member properties, all without imposing any special requirements on the parent class (which doesn't even need to be aware of the composite properties).

Comment: _OP's special request is what got me interested_: fair enough. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack And your bounty got my attention in the first place. To be honest, I'm looking at featured questions not for the points (I've got enough already), but mostly because there's a chance that someone like you found a question interesting enough to warrant more attention. So, thanks for bringing this one up.

Comment: Isn't it the actual reason for which we are contributing to SO? Reputation mining is for someone else. Thank you for the answer. ;-)